# Ubuntu 18.04 go dim despite it's turn off

Tags: 18.04, power-management, screen, settings

I have turned off `dim screen when inactive`, but it doesn't work. I even checked via `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim` if it's really turned off, and the command says, that it is. How can I turn off dim screen when inactive?

Edit: I have found out, that it's caused by my wireless mouse - it has low battery. Can someone help me how to turn off this kind of save power mode?